# Find the minimal polynomial of $T(B)=B^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

> Let $T:M_3(F)\rightarrow M_3(F)$ be a linear transformation defined by $T(B)=B^T$.
>
> Find the minimal polynomial of $T$.

My try:

$T(B)=B^T\implies T^2(B)=B \implies T^3(B)=B^T\implies T^3=T \implies T^3-T=0$

Thus, the minimal polynomial is: $x(x^2-1)=x(x-1)(x+1)$

Since $\ker T=\{0\},$ one can conclude that $T$ is invertible, which means $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$.

But my result for the minimal polynomial shows that $0$ is an eigenvalue.

Could someone please point at my mistake?

Comment: Let $p(x):=x^2-1$. Then $p(T)=T\circ T-\mathrm{Id}\equiv 0$. thus, either $p$ or one of its divisors is the minimal polynom of $T$. It is easy to check, that $p$ must be the one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have found one polynomial, $p(x)=x^3-x$, such that $p(T)=0$. Thus, the minimal polynomial $\mu_T(x)$ **divides** it.

Notice, however, that you had *already* found another polynomial $q$ of degree $2$ such that $q(T)=0$ when you wrote $T^2(B)=B$; it was $q(x)=x^2-1$.

Now, you must prove that no divisor $\widetilde q$ of $x^2-1$ satisfies $\widetilde q(T)=0$. This is, however, rather easy.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. But it feels like I "lost" $0$ as an eigenvalue. Let's say I couldn't see easily that $T$ is invertible, why is that ok to say $0$ is not an eigenvalue?

Comment: For any linear transformation $A$ there are polynomials such that $p(0)=0$ and $p(T)=0$. Namely, $x\mu_A(x)$, $x^2\mu_A(x)$, $x^3(x^{19}+3x+7)\mu_A(x)$ et cetera. So, what happened here in not special.

Comment: I know that, but I still can't see why I could "stop" at $(x-1)(x+1)$ as the minimal polynomial and not $x(x-1)(x+1)$

Comment: Because along the way you happen to have found that $T^2(B)=B$ for all $B$, which means that $T^2-id_{M_{3}(F)}=0$ (fortunately, in this case we need not work in coordinates, but with them it'd be an identity of $9\times 9$ matrices).

Answer (score 3):

You have $T^2(B)=B$ this implies that the minimal polynomial divides $x^2-1$, since it is different of $x-1$ and of $x+1$, it is $x^2-1$.